# How to remove stamps/watermarks from masked images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image that I'm masking, but even the text gets thresholded. Here's a thresdholded image below:

[image]

As you can see, the time, letters and such are also a part of the mask. I want to get rid of them. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images follow that kind of pattern, you could try to apply a [morphological closing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)).

Whith a mask the right size for the closing and opening, it will get rid of the text in the image, leaving it black.

Note that applying a closing may also slightly modify the rest of the image (for instance, a circular mask may smooth the edges of the circle in the center of the mask).

Comment: Simple solution to a simple problem.

Comment: Can you provide an example, because I just tried with a MORPH_RECT 75 by 75 kernel and it completely messed up the mask?

Comment: And did not remove the watermark either.

Comment: 25 by 25 kernel worked!